# Do a button click from code in plotly dash

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

I have 3 buttons that stand side by side on my UI.
When the user clicks one of them, the buttons that are standing right of the clicked button should be also clicked step by step. Is there a way to manage this scenario in plotly-dash?

To show it visually,
[image: buttons]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Make a callback that takes in the 1st button's `n_clicks` prop, and outputs to the 2nd button's `n_clicks` prop. Same for the 2nd to 3rd buttons.

A simple example:

```py
@app.callback(Output('button-2', 'n_clicks'),
              [Input('button-1', 'n_clicks')])
def callback_func(button_clicks):
    if button_clicks:
        return button_clicks
    raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
```